# Mocha interfaces: Uncaught ReferenceError: `describe` is not defined

Tags: mocha.js, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I am using Gulp to run karma with mocha/sinon/chai and jquery

My karma.conf.js has:

```
// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jquery-2.1.0', 'mocha'],

// Plugin specific config
client: {
  mocha: {
    reporter: 'spec',
    ui: 'tdd'
  }
}
```

And the node-modules installed are

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "",
    "gulp": "",
    "gulp-jslint": "",
    "gulp-notify": "",
    "gulp-phpunit": "",
    "gulp-util": "",
    "karma": "",
    "karma-chai": "",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "",
    "karma-cli": "",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "",
    "karma-jquery": "",
    "karma-mocha": "",
    "karma-opera-launcher": "",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "",
    "karma-sinon": "",
    "mocha": "",
    "sinon": "*"
}
```

But when I run karma I get this error

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\path\to\my\project\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js --color --gulpfile c:\path\to\my\project\Gulpfile.js karma:unit
[10:58:05] Using gulpfile c:\path\to\my\project\Gulpfile.js
[10:58:05] Starting 'karma:unit'...
[2015-10-07 10:58:05.142] [DEBUG] config - Loading config c:\path\to\my\project\karma.conf.js
07 10 2015 10:58:05.236:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
07 10 2015 10:58:05.245:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
07 10 2015 10:58:05.249:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
07 10 2015 10:58:06.262:INFO [Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 3C6LlqYiiMMpHEnaAAAA with id 29319610
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
Uncaught ReferenceError: describe is not defined
at c:/path/to/my/project/test/test.class.view.js:7
```

I already tried installing karma-mocha and mocha globally.
I tried having karma-mocha as a plugin on karma.conf.js

Comment: You have bad karma: you try to use something called describe in the 7th line of c:/Projects/INRXInsights/Code/Analytics-UI-Insights/httpdocs/test/test.class.view.js:7 so it looks like a missing dependency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was using 'tdd' for mocha configuration. It should be 'bdd'.

```
// Plugin specific config
client: {
  mocha: {
    reporter: 'spec',
    ui: 'bdd'
  }
}
```

'describe' is exposed if the setup is 'bdd' not 'tdd'

Comment: Good to know, I found what you're saying in [mocha's official site](https://mochajs.org/) (Section: Interfaces). The docs say by default it uses BDD which I think is the reason we took it for granted when we used it before :) It turns out we were using BDD's interfaces to do TDD, haha.